# How to wrap echo div in <a href>

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm running into two problems transferring a Wordpress archive page into a page template.

```
<?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'casestudies', 'posts_per_page' => 12 );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

echo '<div class="casestudy">'.get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, '180,180' ).'</div>';
```

First I need to wrap the echo for the thumbnail with a link in order to trigger a css action:

```
'<a href="'.the_permalink().'" class="anchor-hover">';
```

When I add that a href line it only prints the link, and doesn't wrap the echo.

The a href should then print the title and excerpt over the thumbnail box:

```
 '<span class="details"><div class="anchor-hover details-h3"><?php the_title(); ?></div>';
 '<p class="desc"><?php echo get_post($post_id)->post_excerpt; ?></p></span></a>';

endwhile; ?>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        </div></div>
```

Comment: How about describing what the problem is?

Comment: When I add that '<a href>' line it only prints the link, and doesn't wrap the echo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In wordpress, you have two type types of functions.  One's that return the results, and one's that echo the results.

You are using `the_permalink();` which is already echoing out it's result.

You need to be using `get_the_permalink();` since you are trying to echo it in your template.

Comment: get_permalink worked for that a href, thank you, but how can I get php the_title() and php echo get_post($post_id)->post_excerpt to show up on the cursor hover?

Comment: Again, you need to ensure you are using the function that **returns**, not echos.  Use `get_the_title();` instead of `the_title();`.  Also for the excerpt, use `get_the_excerpt();`

Comment: This code works:

    echo '<div class="casestudy"><a href="'.get_permalink().'" class="anchor-hover">'.get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, '180,180' ).'<span class="details"><div class="anchor-hover details-h3">'.get_the_title().'</div><p class="desc">'.get_the_excerpt().'</p></span></a></div>';

Answer (score 0):

get_permalink worked for that a href, thank you, but how can I get php the_title() and php echo get_post($post_id)->post_excerpt to show up on the cursor hover?

*This code should be working if you are in the loop*

```
<a href="#" title="<?php echo get_the_title() . ' - ' . get_the_excerpt(); ?>">LINK</a>
```

The method **get** in WordPress will give you the string only.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_excerpt
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title